# Mount LVM 1 volume from a loopfile

Tags: linux, lvm

I've come across an old hard disk (+15 years) that contains an image of another disk I created using dd.

By using `losetup`, I can attach it to a loop device.

```
# lsblk -f /dev/loop0
NAME  FSTYPE      FSVER LABEL UUID                                   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
loop0 LVM1_member             qvBl4K-3QK0-wYyg-la09-LGdg-tjCj-Vz5EIu
```

But I cannot mount it

```
# mount /dev/loop0 /mnt
mount: /home/void/mnt: unknown filesystem type 'LVM1_member'.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

So, how should I mount an LVM **1** volume on modern distro?

Comment: LVM1 support was removed in 2018 and buggy before that (lvmetad broke it). Try with LVM 2.02.85 or earlier? Ubuntu 12.04 ISO might work, but it doesn't have LVM2 by default, so you'd also have to edit /etc/apt/sources.list to `old-releases.ubuntu.com` and install it (or find another ISO that included lvm directly). Spin it up in a VM, see if it works...

Comment: @frostschutz Do you mean that [this FAQ](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/lvm2faq.html#AEN343) is obsolete and that LVM2 is no longer backward compatible with LVM1?

Comment: @xhienne the FAQ is from like 2004, so yes, it's ancient and obsolete

Answer (score 0):

An LVM volume like you see is not directly mountable. It is a physical LVM volume (PV) that is attached to an LVM volume group (VG) which itself contains zero, one or many LVM logical volumes (LVs). What you can actually mount is those LVs.

The first step is to make your system see your loop file as a PV with `pvscan`.

If `pvscan` is sucessful, then:

- `pvs` will show your PV and its associated VG
- `lvs name_of_vg` will show the LVs contained in that VG

Usually, for each LV, you will find a corresponding device in `/dev/name_of_vg` (they may have another name/location in `/dev`, though; anyway, since they are managed by device-mapper, they should appear in `dmsetup -ls` which will give you their major/minor device numbers)

Comment: `pvscan` return "No matching physical volume found"

Comment: @GeorgeLivanoss I assume you still have your `/dev/loop0` device. Then your question boils down to « `pvscan` doesn't see my LVM1 volume » (you can Google that). You can check that your `lvm.conf` is not filtering out loop devices.

Comment: Maybe you could restart from the beginning: `losetup -d /dev/loop0` then `kpartx -a /your/dd_file`, then verify that loop devices have been created accordingly, then `pvscan`.

Comment: I think the answer is in the first comment to my question, this is a LVM1 vg, while current distro uses LVM2. I'm gonna try in a vm with an old linux

Comment: @GeorgeLivanoss You are right. Your VM will allow you to do an LVM1->LVM2 conversion, then my answer will still apply.